# How to set multiple handlers in Jetty and not get an error during startup

Tags: java, jetty

I have some server code which looks like this:

```
private WebAppContext getAspireWebAppContext() {
    WebAppContext root = new WebAppContext();
    root.setWar(config().<String>property("war.file"));
    root.setContextPath("/");
    return root;
}

private Server startWebApp(int port) {
  try {
    server.setConnectors(createConnectors(port));
    ServletContextHandler context = getAspireWebAppContext();
    server.setHandler(context);

    // Ensure that a websocket always has a HttpSession
    context.addFilter(HttpSessionForWebsocketFilter.class,"/ws/*",null);
    // add websocket support
    ServerContainer wscontainer = WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext( context );
    wscontainer.addEndpoint(EngineSocket.class);
    wscontainer.addEndpoint(WorkbenchSocket.class);

    server.start();
  } ....
}
```

I want to use a `HandlerList` so I can add a RewriteHandler. So I tried to change it:

```
HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();

server.setConnectors(createConnectors(port));
ServletContextHandler context = getAspireWebAppContext();
// server.setHandler(context);
handlers.addHandler(context);

// Ensure that a websocket always has a HttpSession
context.addFilter(HttpSessionForWebsocketFilter.class,"/ws/*",null);
// add websocket support
ServerContainer wscontainer = WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext( context );
wscontainer.addEndpoint(EngineSocket.class);
wscontainer.addEndpoint(WorkbenchSocket.class);

// RewriteHandler stuff
// handlers.addHandler(rewrite);

server.setHandler(handlers);
server.start();
```

Even before I add any more handlers this causes a null exception on the `WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(context)` line:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:148)

I read somewhere that `context.setServer(server);` might help but to no avail. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `HandlerList` to the server first.

```java
Server server = new Server();
HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
server.setHandler(handlers);

ServletContextHandler context = getAspireWebAppContext();
handlers.addHandler(context);

ServerContainer wscontainer = WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext( context );
wscontainer.addEndpoint(EngineSocket.class);
wscontainer.addEndpoint(WorkbenchSocket.class);

// RewriteHandler stuff
handlers.addHandler(rewrite);

server.start();
```

But ultimately, this NPE is a bug with an internal attempt to fetch a common `HttpClient` from the `Server` that belongs to your `ServletContextHandler`.

Opened as https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/3139

Also of note, you should know that you cannot apply filters to WebSocket connections reliably.

WebSocket upgrades via JSR356 (the API you are choosing to use) is designed to do the upgrade outside of the Filter chain.   This is because a Filter can modify the request/response, change commit state of the response, wrap input streams, wrap output streams, etc.  All of which are forbidden during a WebSocket upgrade.   While your Filter might work some of the time, it will not work 100% of the time.   And the `Set-Cookie` header from such an action isn't guaranteed to be sent back on the response either.

If you switch to the Jetty Native WebSocket API you can control where the upgrade occurs (same forbidden actions apply).  Extend from `WebSocketServlet`, or extend from `WebSocketUpgradeFilter` and apply your own logic, or even better, supply your own `WebSocketCreator` to do what you need.